# Can a query stop Neo4j from working

Tags: neo4j, cypher, server, recommendation-engine

I adapted this recommendation system cypher query from the very helpful book..(Learning Neo4j  By Rik Van Bruggen) to my data set and it basically broke the server.

```
match (p1:Person)-[:BOUGHT]->(prod1:Product)<-[:BOUGHT]-(p2:Person)- [:BOUGHT]->(prod2:Product)

with p1,p2,count(prod1) as NrOfSharedProducts, collect(prod1) as SharedProducts,prod2

where not(p1-[:BOUGHT]->prod2) AND NrOfSharedProducts > 2

return p1.name as FirstPerson, p2.name as SecondPerson, extract(x in SharedProducts | x.name) as SharedProducts, prod2.name as RecommendedProduct;
```

What I mean by "broke the server" is that after the query started 1) the web browser disconnected from the server on and off several times 2) took a real long time and 3) the query failed giving a "unknown error".

I didn't know this could happen. Since I ran the related query immediately before (below) I tried the second and it gave correct output in seconds, I thought I lined things up correctly and it could work.

```
match (p1:Person)-[:BOUGHT]->(prod1:Product)<-[:BOUGHT]-(p2:Person)- [:BOUGHT]->(prod2:Product)

where not (p1-[:BOUGHT]->prod2)

return p1.name as FirstPerson, p2.name as SecondPerson, prod1.name as CommonProduct, prod2.name as RecommendedProduct;
```

Should I be surprised by this failure? Are there known reasons for this? How should I interpret this fail?

Comment: The same query just finished again.  Blew things up again.  Here is what the browser said in a big orange banner across the top of the browser   "disconnected from Neo4j. Please check if the cord is unplugged." Which it isn't.  Then in the browser space it says  "Unknown error." Meanwhile java is chugging away in Top at 98%CPU. Go figure!

Comment: From Neo4j 2.2 there is the option to cancel a query from the UI.

Comment: Which of the two queries didn't perform?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it definitely can!  I like to set the following in the `conf/neo4j-server.properties` file:

```
org.neo4j.server.transaction.timeout=60
```

That way if 60 seconds go by without any result the query is killed.  This is particularly nice if you're playing with a potentially expensive query and running it multiple times in various ways.  If you have multiple queries at the same time doing this in can really slow things down.

Answer (score 1):

For your query

1. try to profile your query in neo4j-shell by prefixing it with `PROFILE`
2. execute the cheap conditions first
3. reduce the cardinality early on,

```
match (p1:Person)-[:BOUGHT]->(prod1:Product) 2
MATCH  (p2)- [:BOUGHT]->(prod2:Product)
where not(p1-[:BOUGHT]->prod2) AND 
return p1.name as FirstPerson, p2.name as SecondPerson, extract(x in SharedProducts | x.name) as SharedProducts, prod2.name as RecommendedProduct;
```